# C# codes to get a list of strings like A to Z?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

How can I get a list of strings from "A:" to "Z:" in C#? Something like this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
   list.Add(string.Format("{0}:", Convert.ToChar('A' + i));
}
```

Sorry I don't have VS available for verification right now to verify. By the way, is there web site available to interactive test snip of codes?

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the nice answers. I really like VS 2008 codes, however, I have to use one for VS 2005.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, not counting missing ')' at the end of list.Ad.... line, everything is ok, altough you could write it using a bit shorter notation

```
list.Add((char)('A' + i) + ":");
```

Comment: That's a lot of unnecessary casting etc though - see my revised solution if you're not keen on LINQ.

Answer (score 14):

```
from ch in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" select ch + ":";
```

Comment: I really like the look of this one.

Comment: Alternatively: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".Select(ch => ch + ":") - same thing, no need for "from" or "in".

Comment: That is a nice one; works also for ranges that do not come in sequence, such as the Swedish alphabet.

Answer (score 12):

Using LINQ:

```
List<string> aToZ = Enumerable.Range('A', 26)
                              .Select(x => (char) x + ":")
                              .ToList();
```

Not using LINQ - a simpler alternative (IMO) to the original for loop:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
{
   list.Add(c + ":");
}
```

Comment: Heh, you used lowercase letters though! (just kidding, we have almost identical answers)

Comment: You English guys are lucky to have an alphabet that comes in sequence ;o)

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Y'all should have marked me down for replying without reading. This doesn't work in VS2005, which is what the OP asked about.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(Enumerable.Range((int)'A', 26).Select(value => ((char)value).ToString() + ':'));
```

Comment: No need to explicitly call ToString you use a string literal on the RHS of the +. Or there's string.Format of course.

Comment: Since it no longer applies, you can delete it.

Comment: It doesn't apply for the OP, but it applies to the title of the thread and perhaps other people perusing things. :)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range('a', 'z' - 'a' + 1).Select(charCode => (char)charCode)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yours works fine with the exception of missing a ).  I test all my snipits with [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).  (I don't know how I ever lived without it).

Answer (score 0):

Other answer ;-)

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
for (int i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++)
{
    list.Add(string.Format("{0}:", Convert.ToChar(i)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For testing code snippets, I use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) or [Snippet Compiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/). I prefer LinqPad but both are very nice.